# How to break a loop in Java where the input size is not previously specified?

Tags: java, array-algorithms

I need to input n numbers, store them in a variable and make them available for later processing.
Constraints: 
1. Any number of SPACES between successive inputs.
2. The count of inputs would be UNKNOWN. 
3. Input set should not exceed 256KB and should be between 0<= i <=10^18

```
Example Input: 
100
                  9 
        81
                              128
1278
```

Comment: anything that the numbers need to comply with (eg. only positive numbers)?

Comment: Yes. Any positive integer would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then yes. One way, is to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and [`hasNextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Double> al = new ArrayList<>();
while (scan.hasNextDouble()) { // <-- when no more doubles, the loop will stop.
  al.add(scan.nextDouble());
}
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is the loop does not seem to stop. Because I entered some 5 numbers. Pressed enter. Nothing happened. My only need with this small problem is, after I have entered any number of values I want, in any way, say I give couple of tabs after the first input, then only one space etc, they should be stored and be available later.Could I achieve that by giving the input command line ? If I can, can I give any number of spaces I want between the inputs ?

Comment: Try typing something that isn't a number. Like stop or quit or done.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. It works fine. But would it be possible to make the loop break with out us typing anything else ? In any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're input is all coming in on one line like in your text, you could do something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Numbers 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String[] inputs = args[0].split(" ");

        for (String input : inputs)
        {
            numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(input));
        }
        //do something clever with numbers array list.
    }
}
```